# How to pin transitive dependency versions across multi-pom Maven project

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I'm working on a large Java codebase that's split into multiple modules, each with a separate pom.xml, all parented by a top-level pom.xml.

I'm currently in the process of bringing in a couple of library dependencies. The transitive set of dependencies is large, and as luck would have it, there are conflicting dependency versions for different modules.

Here's a simplification of my situation:

```
project/pom.xml
       /module-a/pom.xml # references library-a, depends on library-c:v1
       /module-b/pom.xml # references library-b, depends on library-c:v2
       /module-c/pom.xml # references module-a and module-b
```

Now the unit tests for `module-a` will exercise `library-a` in the presence of `library-c:v1`, while `module-b` will exercise `library-b` in the presence of `library-c:v2`.

The trouble is that `module-a` and `module-b` need to live together on the same classpath when `module-c` is deployed, but whatever version of `library-c` is chosen when `module-c` is packaged, at least one combination of libraries hasn't been unit tested!

I'd like to pin the version of `library-c` at the parent pom level somehow, rather than repeating myself in every module that transitively depends on `library-c`; ideally it would be added in such a way indicating that it's a transitive dependency that is allowed to go away should `library-a` and `library-b` no longer rely on it.

I'd like a guarantee that there is exactly one version selected for 
every transitive dependency across the entire project rooted from this parent pom, and I'd like the build to blow up if this isn't true. I wrote a tool to parse the output of `mvn dependency:tree` (turning the leaves of the tree into a forest of paths from leaf to root, then finding all different versions of leaf with the dependency path) so I can see the problem, but without explicitly resolving the transitive dependencies for every conflict and bloating out poms with redundant declarations, this doesn't seem fruitful. It's what I'll do if I have no alternative, naturally.

**What's the best way to handle this transitive dependency conflict problem with Maven?**

How severe is this problem? Quite apart from getting unconvincing test coverage, in practice I see JVM-killing `NoSuchMethodError` at runtime from the wrong versions getting deployed. I'd prefer to see these at test time at the very least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there are two aspects to this:

> 1. You need to insist on a single version of a dependency, whether it is declared explicitly or acquired transitively

You can use [`<dependencyManagement/>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) here. For example in the top-level pom.xml you can pin the version of `library-c`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>library-c</artifactId>
        <version>2</version>
    <dependency>
  <dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

And then in `library-a`, `library-b` you would declare the dependency on `library-c` as follows:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>library-c</artifactId>
  <dependency>
<dependencies>
```

By declaring this dependency in the parent's `dependencyManagement` you are insisting on both of the child modules using the version declared in the parent.

> 2. You want to protect yourself from unhappy dependency additions occurring in future

You can use the [Maven Enforcer plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html) here, specifically the [dependencyConvergence](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) rule. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce</id>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <dependencyConvergence/>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The enforcer can be configured to either fail or warn if it discovers a non convergent dependency.

Comment: I'm already using `dependencyManagement` - in fact I wrote another tool to move all version elements from dependencies in child projects into dependency elements in the management section in the parent pom. For a flavour of the problem, I currently have 20 conflicting versions across 306 transitive dependencies. By your reckoning, I'll need to add 20*x (for x > 2 at least) explicit dependency sections to children. Sounds like a job for another tool.

Comment: Oh and another fun factoid - there are 3519 different dependency paths in total across all dependencies :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a combination of `dependencyManagement` to define-and-insist on versions and `enforcer` to show you where the issues are (for example running the enforcer's `dependencyConvergence` rule with `fail=false` will emit a report much like the one being produced by your tool: "turning the leaves of the tree into a forest of paths from leaf to root, then finding all different versions of leaf with the dependency path"). However, there's no magic spell to create you `dependencyManagement` so given 3519 dependency paths you have some scripting to look forward to. Good luck :)